# How to get Jackson to use its JsonSerializable Interface?

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, jersey

Jackson docs say that a class that implements their **JsonSerializable** interface will be serialized by calling the Interface's serialize() method.

I tried this in a project that uses Jackson 2.8.4 under Jersey 2.25.

It continues to use Jackson's BeanSerializer to do default serialization based on public getters, instead of using the SerializableSerializer and the serialize() method.

Code looks like this fairly minimal example...

```
public class Minimal extends JsonSerializable.Base {

  private String title;
  private ZonedDateTime theTime;


  public String getTitle() { return title; }
  void setTitle(String title) { this.title = title; }
  public ZonedDateTime getTheTime() { return theTime; }
  void setTheTime(ZonedDateTime theTime) { this.theTime = theTime; }

  @Override
  public void serialize(JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
    gen.writeStartObject();
    gen.writeFieldName("title");
    gen.writeString(this.title);
    // Other serialization...
    gen.writeEndObject();
  }

  @Override
  public void serializeWithType(JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers, TypeSerializer typeSer) throws IOException {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported."); 
  }
}
```

I also tried other ideas to get it using the right serializer...maybe foolish ideas like...

```
public class Minimal implements JsonSerializable {
```

and

```
@JsonSerialize(using = SerializableSerializer.class)
public class Minimal extends JsonSerializable.Base {
```

and

```
@JsonSerialize(as = JsonSerializable.Base.class)
public class Minimal extends JsonSerializable.Base {
```

What am I missing to get this Jackson feature working?

I verified in Jackson's latest source code that the feature still exists. I suppose I can trace it through the 2.8.4 source in the debugger, but maybe someone knows the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the answer to

> "What am I missing?"

is **Nothing**.

After writing the question, I rebuilt everything again, restarted Tomcat, and redeployed and tested again and got my expected output.

So I will chalk this up to bad build, bad deploy, confused Classloader, something like that. I am leaving the question, since it provides an example that might help someone.